# Azure Function to raiseEvent is throwing Exception (Java)

Tags: java, azure-functions

I am trying to use raiseEvent feature in azure function, but I am getting an Exception in log. Here is the code snippet below , the ctx.instanceId is TaskOrchestrationContext.instanceId . The raiseEvent is called from with an Orchestrator function

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong here

```
durableClientContext.getClient().raiseEvent(ctx.getInstanceId(), "PUBLISH_EVENTS",
                                        new KafkaPublisherNotifierEvent(input.getActualRequest().getProcessId(), input.getActualRequest().getCconsol()));
```

---

### Exception I see in Log

```
ERROR 12368 --- [ool-2-thread-22] i.g.i.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper        : *~*~*~ Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=85, target=localhost:4001} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
    Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:93) ~[grpc-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:53) ~[grpc-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init>(ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:44) ~[grpc-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(ManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:630) ~[grpc-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:297) ~[grpc-core-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.DurableTaskGrpcClient.<init>(DurableTaskGrpcClient.java:51) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.DurableTaskGrpcClientBuilder.build(DurableTaskGrpcClientBuilder.java:61) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.azurefunctions.DurableClientContext.getClient(DurableClientContext.java:59) ~[durabletask-azure-functions-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.kgtest.engine.functions.orchestrator.MyTestOrchestrator.customTrialOrchestrator(customTrialOrchestrator.java:92) ~[test-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor156.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:22) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.FunctionExecutionMiddleware.invoke(FunctionExecutionMiddleware.java:19) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.InvocationChain.doNext(InvocationChain.java:21) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.azurefunctions.internal.middleware.OrchestrationMiddleware.lambda$invoke$0(OrchestrationMiddleware.java:37) ~[durabletask-azure-functions-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.OrchestrationRunner.lambda$loadAndRun$0(OrchestrationRunner.java:65) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationExecutor$ContextImplTask.processEvent(TaskOrchestrationExecutor.java:821) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationExecutor$ContextImplTask.access$1300(TaskOrchestrationExecutor.java:74) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationExecutor$ContextImplTask$OrchestrationHistoryIterator.moveNext(TaskOrchestrationExecutor.java:930) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationExecutor$ContextImplTask.processNextEvent(TaskOrchestrationExecutor.java:790) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationExecutor$ContextImplTask.access$000(TaskOrchestrationExecutor.java:74) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.TaskOrchestrationExecutor.execute(TaskOrchestrationExecutor.java:52) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.OrchestrationRunner.loadAndRun(OrchestrationRunner.java:135) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.OrchestrationRunner.loadAndRun(OrchestrationRunner.java:69) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.OrchestrationRunner.loadAndRun(OrchestrationRunner.java:42) ~[durabletask-client-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.durabletask.azurefunctions.internal.middleware.OrchestrationMiddleware.invoke(OrchestrationMiddleware.java:34) ~[durabletask-azure-functions-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.chain.InvocationChain.doNext(InvocationChain.java:21) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:125) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:37) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:12) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:44) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:93) ~[azure-functions-java-worker.jar:2.8.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be due to the `ManagedChannel` which is related to gRPC channel used by Durable functions was not properly shut down.

- In case of `raiseEvent`, if the instance is not actively waiting for the specified event, the message is added to an in-memory queue but gRPC channel might not be closed correctly.

***To resolve this, enclose your code with try, catch blocks and shutdown the gRPC channel once done with the process and no longer required.*** Refer [GitHub](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5315).

```java
 ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(localhost,port).build();
    try {
        DurableTaskGrpcClient durableClient = new DurableTaskGrpcClient(channel);
        durableClient.raiseEvent(ctx.getInstanceId(), "PUBLISH_EVENTS", new KafkaPublisherNotifierEvent(input.getActualRequest().getProcessId(), input.getActualRequest().getCconsol()));
    } 
finally {
    try {
        channel.shutdown();
        channel.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //print exception e
      }
    }
```

---

I have created an Durable Orchestrator Azure function and implemented [raiseEvent feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=java#send-events).

```java
 @FunctionName("StartOrchestration")
 public HttpResponseMessage startOrchestration(
         @HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
         @DurableClientInput(name = "durableContext") DurableClientContext durableContext,
         final ExecutionContext context) {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");
    DurableTaskClient client = durableContext.getClient();
    String instanceId = client.scheduleNewOrchestrationInstance("Cities");
    context.getLogger().info("Created new Java orchestration with instance ID = " + instanceId);
    String eventName = "newEventss";
    int[] eventData = { 1, 2, 3 };
    durableContext.getClient().raiseEvent(instanceId, eventName, eventData);
    return durableContext.createCheckStatusResponse(request, instanceId);
    }
```

**Console Output:**

```
Functions:

        StartOrchestration: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/StartOrchestration

        Capitalize: activityTrigger

        Cities: orchestrationTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-28T10:31:20.661Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2024-02-28T10:31:23.919Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-02-28T10:31:33.287Z] Executing 'Functions.StartOrchestration' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=00132826-c449-4164-bd35-d93edb897011)
[2024-02-28T10:31:33.709Z] Java HTTP trigger processed a request.
[2024-02-28T10:31:37.484Z] Created new Java orchestration with instance ID = 1660f4cb-b9b1-4835-90e1-0039f685336a
[2024-02-28T10:31:37.978Z] Executing 'Functions.Cities' (Reason='(null)', Id=e4fa82c8-4198-4355-bf60-9d82ec481698)
[2024-02-28T10:31:38.101Z] Function "Cities" (Id: e4fa82c8-4198-4355-bf60-9d82ec481698) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-02-28T10:31:38.238Z] Function "StartOrchestration" (Id: 00132826-c449-4164-bd35-d93edb897011) invoked by Java Worker
[2024-02-28T10:31:38.244Z] Executed 'Functions.Cities' (Succeeded, Id=e4fa82c8-4198-4355-bf60-9d82ec481698, Duration=231ms)
[2024-02-28T10:31:38.335Z] Executed 'Functions.StartOrchestration' (Succeeded, Id=00132826-c449-4164-bd35-d93edb897011, Duration=5154ms)
```

- Checking the raiseEvent status
  [image]

Sending the `eventData` to an orchestrator instance waiting for an event named `newEventss` by browsing the URL:

```
http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/1660f4cb-b9b1-4835-90e1-0039f685336a/raiseEvent/newEventss?code=1Dya87P2y-mHGfFQOkt6B_5EbzG5Vd-Uj8w0MBoMYtf9AzFu2G2jGA==
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, in the response you created a ManagedChannel  using host, port value. Can you please tell how can I get this host and port value